# License Dependency Report

Tags: untagged

The usage of open source software (OSS) often comes with the risk of [patent infringements](https://www.iusmentis.com/computerprograms/opensourcesoftware/patentrisks/). Companies who want to use OSS have to take care of the specific license terms and obligations that come with the software and its dependencies.

**Questions:**

Is it possile to generate a dependency report listing the name, repository and license of the used dependecies from the Tezos project?

**Goal:**

With this information I would be able to check the compatibility of all licenses with each other and if they comply with company rules. Imagine a node running in a product like a mobile phone that can be sold and each has a Tezos client rolling node running. The company could be sued for the distribution and usage of the software or more likely for certain parts of it e.g. due to dependecies.

Edit:
There is apparently a standard for this called [SPDX](https://spdx.org/)

Comment: Question is not obviously about Tezos... You could try asking in an OCaml forum, where you will find more OCaml fans. Maybe `odig` can be useful.

Comment: Fair point - somehow I assumed that all ocaml people are gathered here haha